# Where can I find a replacement bracket for my glass counter top?

Tags: bathroom, sink, mounting

Sorry if this is obvious but I'm having a hard time contacting the manufacturer so I wanted to ask here.

I'm trying to replace my mounting brackets on a bathroom sink I have and was wondering if there are any generic or similar parts that would work.

[image: Mounting Bracket attached to wall]

[image: Mounting bracket from another angle]

Comment: The sink is very similar to this model:

http://www.kokolsinc.com/product/23-inch-wall-mounted-single-espresso-wood-pedestal-bathroom-vanity-include-clear-vessel-sink-faucet-kk09/

Comment: Try a glass company or glass shop.

Answer (score -1):

I actually found out that I can actually just use glass shelf brackets.

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining exactly what brackets you chose and why you chose them, how you installed them, etc. Anything that might give some help to future readers facing the same problem. Thanks!